# How to compress webcam videos recorded by html5 MediaRecorder api?

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, webrtc, web-mediarecorder

I successfully recorded my webcam using MediaRecorder api and the resulting filesizes seemed far too big for their quality.

For example, for an 8 second video that was 480x640 I got a 1mB file size. That does not seem right.

My code to record()

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})
    .then(function(stream){
        var options = {
            mimeType : "video/webm;codecs=vp9"
            //I don't set bitrate here even if I do the quality is too bad
        }
        var media_recorder = new MediaRecorder(media_stream, options);
        var recorded_data = [];
        media_recorder.ondataavailable = function(e){
             recorded_data.push(e.data);
        }
        media_recorder.onstop = function(e){
            recorded_data.push(e.data);
            var recorded_blob = new Blob(recorded_data, { 'type' : 'video/webm; codecs=vp9' });
            var recorded_video_url = window.URL.createObjectURL(recorded_blob);
            //here I write some code to download the blob from this url through a href
        }
    })
```

The file obtained by this method is unreasonably large which makes me wonder if it was even compressed when encoded by VP9? A 7 second video is about 870kB!

Inspecting the file with a mediainfo tool gives me

```
General
Count                                    : 323
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : General
Kind of stream                           : General
Stream identifier                        : 0
Count of video streams                   : 1
Count of audio streams                   : 1
Video_Format_List                        : VP9
Video_Format_WithHint_List               : VP9
Codecs Video                             : V_VP9
Video_Language_List                      : English
Audio_Format_List                        : Opus
Audio_Format_WithHint_List               : Opus
Audio codecs                             : Opus
Audio_Language_List                      : English
Complete name                            : recorded_video.webm
File name                                : recorded_video
File extension                           : webm
Format                                   : WebM
Format                                   : WebM
Format/Url                               : http://www.webmproject.org/
Format/Extensions usually used           : webm
Commercial name                          : WebM
Format version                           : Version 2
Internet media type                      : video/webm
Codec                                    : WebM
Codec                                    : WebM
Codec/Url                                : http://www.webmproject.org/
Codec/Extensions usually used            : webm
File size                                : 867870
File size                                : 848 KiB
File size                                : 848 KiB
File size                                : 848 KiB
File size                                : 848 KiB
File size                                : 847.5 KiB
File last modification date              : UTC 2017-05-19 05:48:00
File last modification date (local)      : 2017-05-19 17:48:00
Writing application                      : Chrome
Writing application                      : Chrome
Writing library                          : Chrome
Writing library                          : Chrome
IsTruncated                              : Yes

Video
Count                                    : 332
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : Video
Kind of stream                           : Video
Stream identifier                        : 0
StreamOrder                              : 1
ID                                       : 2
ID                                       : 2
Unique ID                                : 62101435245162993
Format                                   : VP9
Commercial name                          : VP9
Codec ID                                 : V_VP9
Codec ID/Url                             : http://www.webmproject.org/
Codec                                    : V_VP9
Codec                                    : V_VP9
Width                                    : 640
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 480
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Pixel aspect ratio                       : 1.000
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.333
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : VFR
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Language                                 : en
Language                                 : English
Language                                 : English
Language                                 : en
Language                                 : eng
Language                                 : en
Default                                  : Yes
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Forced                                   : No

Audio
Count                                    : 272
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : Audio
Kind of stream                           : Audio
Stream identifier                        : 0
StreamOrder                              : 0
ID                                       : 1
ID                                       : 1
Unique ID                                : 32224324715799545
Format                                   : Opus
Format/Url                               : http://opus-codec.org/
Commercial name                          : Opus
Internet media type                      : audio/opus
Codec ID                                 : A_OPUS
Codec ID/Url                             : http://opus-codec.org
Codec                                    : Opus
Codec                                    : Opus
Codec/Family                             : PCM
Channel(s)                               : 1
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Channel positions                        : Front: C
Channel positions                        : 1/0/0
Sampling rate                            : 48000
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay                                    : 718
Delay                                    : 718ms
Delay                                    : 718ms
Delay                                    : 718ms
Delay                                    : 00:00:00.718
Delay, origin                            : Container
Delay, origin                            : Container
Language                                 : en
Language                                 : English
Language                                 : English
Language                                 : en
Language                                 : eng
Language                                 : en
Default                                  : Yes
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Forced                                   : No
```

What did I do wrong? Do I have to re-encode it after the chunks get appended? Is there some attribute I'm missing? VP9 is supposed to reduce file sizes drastically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome's VP9 single pass encoder for video captured through Media Recorder API is not where you'll see major differences between VP9 and H.264.

When recording webcam video the webcam quality, available light and what you are recording has a bigger impact than what video codec you are using:

- low light => low fps => lower bitrate
- but noise in low light conditions is a lot harder to encode efficiently
- better webcams capture more data with less noise in any light condition
- talking heads need a lower bitrate than lots of movement

But 1MB for every 8-10s @ 640x480 30fps is in line with my findings. I used [this demo](https://addpipe.com/media-recorder-api-demo/) which tries to use VP9, H.264 and VP8 (in this order).

> VP9 is supposed to reduce file sizes drastically.

Compared to H.264 [VP9 does reduce size by about 30%](https://blogs.gnome.org/rbultje/2015/09/28/vp9-encodingdecoding-performance-vs-hevch-264/) but to see the reduction you need to use 2 pass encoding, a very good encoder (they differ) and lots of CPU power. The process will also take significantly longer.